# SpringBoot enable SSL for https but disable it for websocket

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, websocket

We use SpringBoot to develop our server application and we want to secure the communication between the server and clients using https. We use websocket to broadcast events to connected clients and since the broadcasts are public in nature we would like to disable SSL for websocket communication. Is it possible to get this done using SpringBoot?